# Getting a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" error while importing raster files from PostGIS to Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, postgis-2.0

I am trying to import raster data from PostGIS to GeoServer.

I follow the instructions given on this link.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html

I used the **gdal_retile** to make tiles of my GTiff imagery. **I configured xml files** and placed them at desire place. Then I used the **DDL generation utility** which create 4 SQL scripts file, then **I ran the SQL scripts**. But when I **start importing** the image tiles, 61 tiles got inserted then an error comes **"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError".**

---

There is change in the error...
I am attaching the screenshot, please have a look.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you import using the `java -jar ...` command you can add parameters to control how much memory will be given to the JVM running that program. Try the following:

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx512m ...
```

If that doesn't work, increase both numbers to `1024` or `2048`.

Comment: Its not working.... not even after increasing the no. to 1024 or 2048

Comment: Can you paste the full error you are getting?